# Getting data from MySQL DB using PHP highstock

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, highcharts

Of some reason I can't seem to get this to work with highstock range selector. The navigator and range selector is not displaying correct data groups. The default data grouping doesn't work. The data displays correct in highcharts:

As you can see, the data grouping doesn't work when clicking on the navigator zoom panel. Also the columns are not increasing

http://marialaustsen.com/htdocs/index.html

What am I missing?

Many thanks

PHP script PDO call

```
//Checking if a request has been made
if( isset( $_POST ) ) {

    //Establishing connection and retrieving the data 
    try {
        $con = new PDO( 'mysql:dbname=output;host=localhost', 'root', 'root' );
        $results = $con->query( 'SELECT sent_ecards, date FROM details ORDER BY details.date' );
    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    if( isset( $results ) ) {
        $data = [];
        $categories = [];
        $combined = [];

        foreach( $results as $row ) {
        array_push( $categories, $row['date'] );
        array_push( $data, (int) $row['sent_ecards'] );
        }

        array_push( $combined, $data );
        array_push( $combined, $categories );

        header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        echo json_encode( $combined );
    }

}
```

Index file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Send eCards</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>

    <button data-action="retrieve_data">Retrieve New Data</button>


<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

        //Sending request to the server on button click
    $( '[data-action="retrieve_data"]' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'retrieve-data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            //async: true,
            //dataType: "json",

                success: function( data ) {
                console.log( data );
                var axis = $( '#container' ).highcharts().get( 'datetime' ),
                series = $( '#container' ).highcharts().get( 'rewards' );

                axis.setCategories( data[1], false );
                series.setData( data[0], false );
                $( '#container' ).highcharts().redraw();
            },

        })



    //Initializing basic chart configuration object
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            alignTicks: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Send ecards'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        xAxis: {

                type: 'datetime',

                tickInterval:24 * 3600 * 1000 * 365,

            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b \'%y', this.value);
                                       }
            },


            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            },

            id: 'datetime'

            },


        yAxis: {

            title: {
                text: 'Amount of ecards'
            }
            },

        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' K',
            useHTML: true,
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF </span> <b>{point.series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.1f}%)<br/>',
            formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x);
    },
        },

        series: [{
        name: 'ecards',
        id: 'rewards',

        data: [],
        pointInterval: 24*3600*1000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010,0,1)  

        }],

    });

    //$( '#container' ).(chartConfigOptions);

});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The data arrays from consol:

```
(2) [Array(1999), Array(1999)]
0
:
(1999) [843, 2, 544, 81, 45, 12, 454, 81, 45, 466, 3557, 578, 5, 3434, 65, 843, 3435, 544, 65, 843, 4324, 454, 323, 45, 3435, 544, 323, 45, 2, 546, 323, 45, 739, 3557, 342, 235, 2, 546, 342, 235, 565, 342, 235, 2432, 56, 3456, 2432, 56, 2432, 4543, 5, 3456, 2311, 5, 2839, 565, 5, 2839, 65, 4927, 2, 565, 7, 2, 544, 863, 29, 4324, 454, 5, 346, 466, 565, 5, 346, 2311, 454, 264, 68, 343, 546, 29, 4324, 454, 546, 29, 235, 565, 34, 346, 4324, 454, 34, 346, 739, 3557, 34, 346, 98, 454, …]
1
:
(1999) ["01/01/2010", "01/01/2011", "01/01/2012", "01/01/2013", "01/01/2014", "01/01/2015", "01/02/2010", "01/02/2011", "01/02/2012", "01/02/2013", "01/02/2014", "01/02/2015", "01/03/2010", "01/03/2011", "01/03/2012", "01/03/2013", "01/03/2014", "01/03/2015", "01/04/2010", "01/04/2011", "01/04/2012", "01/04/2013", "01/04/2014", "01/04/2015", "01/05/2010", "01/05/2011", "01/05/2012", "01/05/2013", "01/05/2014", "01/05/2015", "01/06/2010", "01/06/2011", "01/06/2012", "01/06/2013", "01/06/2014", "01/06/2015", "01/07/2010", "01/07/2011", "01/07/2012", "01/07/2013", "01/07/2014", "01/08/2010", "01/08/2011", "01/08/2012", "01/08/2013", "01/08/2014", "01/09/2010", "01/09/2011", "01/09/2012", "01/09/2013", "01/09/2014", "01/10/2010", "01/10/2011", "01/10/2012", "01/10/2013", "01/10/2014", "01/11/2010", "01/11/2011", "01/11/2012", "01/11/2013", "01/11/2014", "01/12/2010", "01/12/2011", "01/12/2012", "01/12/2013", "01/12/2014", "02/01/2010", "02/01/2011", "02/01/2012", "02/01/2013", "02/01/2014", "02/01/2015", "02/02/2010", "02/02/2011", "02/02/2012", "02/02/2013", "02/02/2014", "02/02/2015", "02/03/2010", "02/03/2011", "02/03/2012", "02/03/2013", "02/03/2014", "02/03/2015", "02/04/2010", "02/04/2011", "02/04/2012", "02/04/2013", "02/04/2014", "02/04/2015", "02/05/2010", "02/05/2011", "02/05/2012", "02/05/2013", "02/05/2014", "02/05/2015", "02/06/2010", "02/06/2011", "02/06/2012", "02/06/2013", …]
```

Comment: hay can you explain what is not working exactly ?

Comment: http://marialaustsen.com/htdocs/index.html

Comment: As you can see, the data grouping doesn't work when clicking on the navigator zoom panel. Also the columns are not increasing